# Live chat application using Node JS Socket IO and JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, socket.io, forever

I am developing a Live chat application using Node JS, Socket IO and JSON file. I am using JSON file to read and write the chat data. Now I am stuck on one issue, When I do the stress testing i.e pushing continuous messages into the JSON file, the JSON format becomes invalid and my application crashes.Although I am using forever.js which should keep application up but still the application crashes. 
Does anybody have idea on this?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are you using a file in the first place?

Comment: Because I dont want to use DB to save records. And secondly the read/write becomes faster from file.

Comment: A key-value store or even a relational database will still be faster than disk IO. Test it out.

Comment: You said the JSON format becomes invalid and application crashes... how'd forever.js help you because when it will again start your app it will again find that JSON format invalid. You should use 'mongodb' because it supports fast insertion and retrieval. I have personal experience, NoSQL databases like mongodb are much faster than SQL databases and file systems.

Comment: I am keeping separate JSON file for each chat. So my point is if any one chat file becomes invalid, it should not crash the application, it should only stops the chat with invalid JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you re-consider your approach for persisting data to disk.

Among other things, one really big issue is that you will likely experience data loss. If we both get the file at the exact same time - `{"foo":"bar"}` -  we both make a change and you save it before me, my change will overwrite yours since I started with the same thing as you. Although you saved it before me, I didn't re-open it after you saved.

What you are possibly seeing now in an append-only approach is that we're both adding bits and pieces without regard to valid JSON structure (IE: `{"fo"bao":r":"ba"for"o"}` from `{"foo":"bar"}` x 2).

Disk I/O is actually pretty slow. Even with an SSD hard drive. Memory is where it's at.

As recommended, you may want to consider [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), or otherwise. This may be a decent use case for [Couchbase](http://couchbase.com) which is an in-memory key/value store based on memcache that persists things to disk ASAP. It is extremely JSON friendly (it is actually mostly based on JSON), offers great map/reduce support to query data, is super easy to scale to multiple servers, and has a node.js [module](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode).

This would allow you to very easily migrate your existing data storage routine into a database. Also, it provides [CAS](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/cb-cas.html) support which will prevent you from data loss in the scenarios outlined earlier.

At minimum though, you should possibly just modify an in memory object that you save to disk ever so often to prevent permanent data loss. However, this only works well with 1 server and then you're back at likely needing to look at a database.